# How to Search query in yandex webmaster?

Tags: android-music-player

I have linked my blogger site [hindilyricsonline.in](https://hindilyricsonline.in) to yandexwebmaster tools and everything was just working fine. But after when I customized it's url [hindilyricsonline.in](https://hindilyricsonline.in)to  Indexing, Crowling, Sitemap all are still working fine except Search Queries. There is not any data showing in Search Queries on Webmaster tools. If I'm setting webmaster tools again for new url there may be problem of duplicate contents. Also I don't want to remove already indexed pages.